# Port issue with Docker for Windows

Tags: docker

I'm trying to follow [the beginner tutorial](https://training.play-with-docker.com/beginner-linux/) at training.play-with-docker.com. At Task 2, step 6, I do the following and get the error as below:

```
PS C:\Users\david.zemens\Source\Repos\linux_tweet_app> docker container run --detach --publish 80:80 --name linux_tweet_app $DOCKERID/linux_tweet_app:1.0
d39667ed1deafc382890f312507ae535c3ab2804907d4ae495caaed1f9c2b2e1
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint linux_tweet_app (a819223be5469f4e727daefaff3e82eb68eb0674e4a46ee1a32e703ce4bd384d): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

I am using Docker Desktop on a Win10 machine locally. I've tried resetting Docker as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40668908/running-docker-for-windows-error-when-exposing-ports). Error persists. Since something else must be using port 80, **I should be able to avoid the error by using a different port**, right?

```
PS C:\Users\david.zemens\Source\Repos\linux_tweet_app> docker container run --detach --publish 1337:1337 --name linux_tweet_app $DOCKERID/linux_tweet_app:1.0
```

**Right!** `docker ps` now confirms the container is running:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                     NAMES
b700df12c2d1        dzemens/linux_tweet_app:1.0   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:1337->1337/tcp   linux_tweet_app
```

But when I try to view the webpage that the tutorial sends me to, I get an error in the browser.

[image]

I'm not sure how the link is dynamically generated but it looks something like this:

```
http://ip172-18-0-32-blsfgt2d7o0g00epuqi0-80.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com/
```

Browser error as below:

```
The proxy could not connect to the destination in time.
URL: http://ip172-18-0-32-blsfgt2d7o0g00epuqi0-80.direct.labs.play-with-docker.com/
Failure Description: :errno: 104 - 'Connection reset by peer' on socketfd -1:server state 7:state 9:Application response 502 cannotconnect
```

Another [highly-upvoted answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49564445/1467082) I need to "disable Windows 10 fast startup" -- I have not tried this yet, mainly because I'm not sure what the full repercussions are with that setting.

Is there something stupidly obvious that I'm overlooking here? Shouldn't I be able to run this on different ports? If not, why not? If I have to use 80:80, but System is already using that port, won't I have some further problems if I try to kill that pid?

```
PS C:\Users\david.zemens\Source\Repos\linux_tweet_app> netstat -a -n -o | findstr :80 | findstr LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8003           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1348
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8081           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4688
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8080         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2016
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8082         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       28536
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:8003              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:8080              [::]:0                 LISTENING       1348
  TCP    [::]:8081              [::]:0                 LISTENING       4688
```

I made a small change in the `Dockerfile` changing `EXPOSE 80 443` to `EXPOSE 1337 443` and I'm now able to view my app by navigating to localhost:1337 in my browser. **I think that will get me through the next steps in the training module, but still curious if I'm doing something wrong.**

This seems to work regardless of the change in `Dockerfile` (I've removed and republished after changing Dockerfile).

```
PS C:\Users\david.zemens\Source\Repos\linux_tweet_app> docker container run --detach --publish 1337:80 --name linux_tweet_app $DOCKERID/linux_tweet_app:1.0
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A part of the problem is that you're using the wrong mapping. The application uses the port 80, but you're mapping the ports 1337 to 1337.

The correct command should be:

```
PS C:\Users\david.zemens\Source\Repos\linux_tweet_app> docker container run --detach --publish 1337:80 --name linux_tweet_app $DOCKERID/linux_tweet_app:1.0
```

Comment: OK, sorry, so the Dockerfile change I made above was not necessary (seems to work either way???) and I had already done this with ` --publish 1337:80`. That's how I am able to view on localhost:1337

Comment: I think this solves it, and the link not working on the training website I think is a bug/error on their end unrelated to this. I'll just view output on localhost rather than their custom URL.

Comment: sorry for the late answer, I didn't notice that the browser was open on the right port. I should have paid more attention

Answer (score 46):

Try this

```
> net stop winnat
> docker start ...
> net start winnat
```

Comment: I don't know how do you manage to find that but this definitively fix my issue on issue on port 3306 !
Thanks !

Comment: This helped me as well. Thank you.

Comment: Worked very well! Thanks!

Comment: Any context as to why this works? 3306/MySQL was just playing up for me.

Answer (score 8):

It may be because your IIS or some other server is already running on port 80.
Try stop the IIS and it should work.

Reference: https://forums.docker.com/t/error-starting-userland-proxy-listen-tcp-0-0-0-0-bind-an-attempt-was-made-to-access-a-socket-in-a-way-forbidden-by-its-access-permissions/81299/7

Comment: That was my case!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **--port-cdn=9002** at the end of the command while you run your project. (9002 can be changed to any other available port.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).