# Docker container doesn't run on windows , Ports are not available

Tags: windows, docker, devops, docker-container

I was trying to run the docker container on windows 10 but I always get this error **"Cannot start service SERVICE_NAME: Ports are not available: unable to list exposed ports: Get "http://unix/forwards/list": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)"**
. I tried deleting the container and rebuilding it again but that is not working for me.

PS: this error is not related to a specific service, each time happens in a different service although the same service was started successfully before

Any help, please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Docker for Windows, Error when exposing Ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40668908/running-docker-for-windows-error-when-exposing-ports)

Comment: @ceejayoz No, I have tried the solutions, none of them work for me

Comment: In what way are you trying to run the container? - Can you share the command and dockerfile/image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helped me solve the same problem

```
netsh winsock reset
```

Comment: Worked for me too [Thumbs Up]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Hyper-V in Windows, which reserves a range of ports for its needs. This range may overlap with ports that Docker images use.

You need to run the following commands in CMD or PowerShell:

```
netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384
netsh int ipv6 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384
```

After executing the commands, you must restart your computer.

This will forcefully limit the range from which Hyper-V can reserve ports for its needs.
Of cause Docker images shouldn't use ports from 49152 to 65536 because this range can be used by Hyper-V or Windows.